# Issue while connecting to SQL Server from SQL Server Management Studio

Tags: sql-server, ssms, msdn, ssms-2017

We are facing a strange issue while trying to Connect to any SQL Server from the SSMS tool. We tried using version 17.9.1 and v18 Preview 7. Both are having the same issue. We are getting the below error while trying to connect to the database server:

[image]

Also, while trying to click on 'New Query' button, nothing happens. Tried repairing and uninstalling and reinstalling the SSMS tool, but did not help. Any idea why the error is happening?

Comment: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/67011f3e-ffab-4fba-87d5-23a31d44136a/service-microsoftsqlservermanagementiregistrationservice-in-sql-server-management-studio?forum=sqldatabaseengine

Comment: @ZaynulAbadinTuhin That is already tried